# iOS Mountable file system DMG or ISO

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, filesystems

We are creating an iOS application which uses thousands of images, currently we are installing our app then copying the files to the apps document folder.

On a Windows Desktop we use an ISO or VHD file and then mount the storage.

Does anyone know of a mountable file system for iOS? I know they have DMG on OSX but I cant find any information about it being supported on iOS.

The reason I would like to use a mountable storage is that it allows me to copy the files faster as one large file instead of small individual files.

I've looked into copying the files as a zip file but decompressing the files takes to long.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are copying mass data to Documents from the app bundle, your app will likely be rejected during the app review process (see https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/). Files that can be regenerated or downloaded should go into the caches directory where they are not backed up and can be deleted when there is low disk space. Why do you need to store the images outside of the app bundle anyway?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this application will not be going into the Apple AppStore its just an internal application.

Comment: Considering using ZIP without compression or TAR. It'll be much faster.